# Javascript: How to use apply method to pass array of parameter and then access it inside the called function

Tags: javascript, arguments

I am having a problem with the Function.prototype.apply method. Below is my testing source:

```
function callMe(array){
    var s = "";
    s += array; //<--- I want to access the array's member here, eg. array[0], array[1], ...
    return s;
}
var myArr = ["begin", 1, 2, 3, 4, "end"];
console.log(callMe.apply(this, myArr));
```

I want to access the arguments but don't want to specify each param in the function calling as `callMe.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3)`. What I want is `callMe.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, arg3])` and then, inside the called function, I will access the arguments as:

```
array[0] = "yeah";
array[1] = 200;
array[2] = 150;
array[3] = "fine";
```

The output of the code above is just "begin", while I expect it as `["begin", 1, 2, 3, 4, "end"]`.
What's wrong here? Because as I know, `Function.prototype.apply` method is used with separate parameter as `callMe.apply(this, arrayOfArguments)` and this does not work. Whereas, the method `call()` is working fine.
Eg. with the example above, I just replace the apply method with call method and it returns exactly what I want. What have I done wrongly?
I want to use the apply method, not the call method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) takes two arguments. Second argument is an argument array, so your code is doing something like this:

```
function callMe(array){
    var s = "";
    s += array;
    return s;
}
var myArr = ["begin", 1, 2, 3, 4, "end"];
callMe.apply(this, myArr); //SAME AS callMe(myArr[0],myArr[1],myArr[2],myArr[3],myArr[4],myArr[5]);
```

So `callMe.apply(this, myArr)` in this case is the same as `callMe(myArr[0])`.

You have to do something like this:

```
callMe.apply(this, [myArr]);
```

Or like in previous answer (ft1).

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm.
It is a pity that this small piece of example is not clearly mentioned in other coding sites.
Thanks so much Wojciechowski.

Comment: No problem :) It was a pleasure :D